# Detect U Shaped Edges in an Image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, pattern-matching, edge-detection

I'm trying to detect the location of a fingertip from an image. I've been able to crop out a region in the image where it must have a fingertip, and extract the edges using Canny Edge Detector. However I'm stuck. Since my project description says I can't use the skin color for detection, I cannot find the exact contour of the finger, and will have to try to separate the fingertip with edges alone. Right now I'm thinking since the finger has a curved arch shape/letter U shape, maybe that could be used for detection. But since it has to be rotation/scale invariant, most algorithms I found so far are not up to it. Does anyone have an idea of how to do this? Thanks for anyone that responds!
[image]

This is the result I have now. I want to put a bounding box around the index fingertip, or the highest fingertip, whichever is the easiest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recognizing and extracting a pattern using OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670752/recognizing-and-extracting-a-pattern-using-opencv)

Comment: The space between two fingers may also be an U shape

Comment: I deleted the previous one. Yeah that's why I'm only considering upside down u-shapes. I will be happy if I can find any U shapes at all.

Comment: can you robustly extract the contour of the hand? after that you could try fitting parabolas in each neighborhood along the contour.

Answer (score 2):

You may view the tip of U as a corner, and try corner detection method such as the [Foerstner Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection#The_F.C3.B6rstner_corner_detector) that will position of a corner with sub-pixel accuracy, and [Haris corner detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection#The_Harris_.26_Stephens_.2F_Plessey_.2F_Shi.E2.80.93Tomasi_corner_detection_algorithm) which has [implementation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html) included in the feature2D class in opencv.

There is a very clear and straighforward [lecture on Haris corner detector](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rcollins/CSE486/lecture06.pdf) that I would like to share with you.